# Web service doesn't accept xml element with namespace specified on Glassfish

Tags: java, xml, soap, glassfish

I am migrating web service from Weblogic to Glassfish and have encountered very strange behaviour. Previously when I sent this xml to service it was parsed correctly:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:NS1="http://croc/WS_get_ota_info_for_K2.wsdl">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <NS1:courses >
            <NS1:String_1>filter value</NS1:String_1>
        </NS1:courses>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But after I have migrated to Glassfish 4.1.2 value from element String_1 was not used as method parameter. Null was passed instead of "filter value". But when I changed xml to this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:NS1="http://croc/WS_get_ota_info_for_K2.wsdl">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <NS1:courses >
            <String_1>filter value</String_1>
        </NS1:courses>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

everything came back to normal. This xml was also valid for previous version of service that works on weblogic.

What is the reason of such behavior? WSDL was not changed so I expected my service to work the same way on both web servers.

Here is my WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<wsdl:definitions
     name="WS_get_ota_info_for_K2"
     targetNamespace="http://croc/WS_get_ota_info_for_K2.wsdl"
     xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
     xmlns:tns="http://croc/WS_get_ota_info_for_K2.wsdl"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
     xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/">
    <wsdl:types>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="WS_get_ota_info_for_K2_courses">
        <wsdl:part name="String_1" type="xsd:string"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="WS_get_ota_info_for_K2_coursesResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="result" type="xsd:string"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="WS_get_ota_info_for_K2">
        <wsdl:operation name="courses" parameterOrder="String_1">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:WS_get_ota_info_for_K2_courses"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:WS_get_ota_info_for_K2_coursesResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="WS_get_ota_info_for_K2" type="tns:WS_get_ota_info_for_K2">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="courses">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://croc/WS_get_ota_info_for_K2.wsdl/courses"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://croc/WS_get_ota_info_for_K2.wsdl" parts="String_1"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://croc/WS_get_ota_info_for_K2.wsdl" parts="result"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="WS_get_ota_info_for_K2">
        <wsdl:port name="WS_get_ota_info_for_K2Port" binding="tns:WS_get_ota_info_for_K2">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:7101/WS_get_ota_info_for_K2/WS_get_ota_info_for_K2Port"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

and Java class

```
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Clob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
@WebService(name = "WS_get_ota_info_for_K2", serviceName = "WS_get_ota_info_for_K2",
            targetNamespace = "http://croc/WS_get_ota_info_for_K2.wsdl", portName = "WS_get_ota_info_for_K2Port",
            wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/WS_get_ota_info_for_K2.wsdl")
public class WSGetOtaInfoForK2Impl {
    private static final String DATA_SOURCE = "jdbc/mainDS";
    protected DataSource __dataSource = null;

    public WSGetOtaInfoForK2Impl() throws NamingException {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        __dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(DATA_SOURCE);
    }

    @WebResult(name = "result", partName = "result")
    @WebMethod(action = "http://croc/WS_get_ota_info_for_K2.wsdl/courses")
    public String courses(@WebParam(name = "String_1", partName = "String_1") String string1) throws SQLException {
        String response = calculateSomething(string1);
        return response;
    }
}
```